# D3.js: get text of selected dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, select, dropdown

I have a Dropdown Select like this and would like to retrieve the Text of the selected option using D3.js

```
<select id = "dropdown">
   <option value = "Activity1">Watch TV< /option>
   <option value = "Activity2">Sleep</option>
   <option value = "Activity3">Study</option>
</select>"
```

I can get the value of my selection by using :
var ActivityNumber = d3.select("#dropdown").property("value") ;

However i am am needing needing help to retrieve the text of the selection.
 - Either "Watching TV" or "Sleep" or "Study" based on the browser selection..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS selector you need is 'option:checked'.

So to get the currently selected value using D3 with your markup you would use the following code:

```
const selectedText = d3.select('#dropdown option:checked').text();
```

Comment: Thank you.. Is this syntax available in the d3 reference document? couldn't find it..

Comment: Hi @bikster, 
It's not in the D3 documentation as the selector syntax is part of CSS rather than being specific to D3. A good overview of the available selectors is this one on the MDN site... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors